# Url.Action: Passing multiple variables

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

After reading a few other threads it seemed like we needed to map a new route in Global.asax.cs in order to be pass multiple variables. *(note: it works fine if just passing one variable)*

However if passing multiple variables the first one goes through but the second one (and any other ones after that) do not pass through -- their value is null.

As an example the url value in _Layout.cshtml is `var url = '/Home/DidItWork?testUserName=James%20Bond&amp;testEmail=james.bond%40gmail.com';` -- should that be coming out differently since the MapRoute is expecting something in the form of `Home/DidItWork/{testUserName}/{testEmail}`?

Thoughts or suggestions for why it's not passing multiple variables?

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "MyNewRoute",                                              // Route name 
        "Home/DidItWork/{testUserName}/{testEmail}",                           // URL with parameters 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "DidItWork" }  // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DidItWork(string testUserName, string testEmail)
{
        var manager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "user name", Email = "username@gmail.com" };
        var result = await manager.CreateAsync(user, "passwordGoesHere1!");
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await manager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, testUserName, testEmail);

            return View();
        }
        return View();    
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
    @*script for someone who presses the send/email button*@ 
<script>
$("#sendButton").click(function () {
    var htmlBody = $("#myModal .modal-body").text();
    var url = '@Url.Action("DidItWork", "Home", new { testUserName = "James Bond", testEmail = "james.bond@gmail.com" })';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Success. It worked." + htmlBody);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            alert("Sorry, there was a problem! Error: " + errorThrown + ". Status: " + status + ". Console: " + xhr);
            console.log("Hello");
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
            console.log("Status: " + status);
            console.dir(xhr);
            console.log("Good-bye");
        },
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you add `console.log(url);` immediately before the `$.ajax(..` you will see that it produces `/Test/DidItWork/James%20Bond/james.bond%40gmail.com `. If not then you have other issues. In any case it wont hit the controller because of the dots (from the email address) in the url.

Comment: When I add console.log(url) it shows `/Home/DidItWork?testUserName=James%20Bond&amp;testEmail=james.bond%40gmail.com` -- the weird thing is that it works when there is only one variable, even the email variable when the console.log(url)  output shows `/Home/DidItWork?testEmail=james.bond%40gmail.com`

Comment: I pasted you code into a new project (only thing I changed was to use  `ActionResult` instread of  `async Task<ActionResult>` i.e. `public ActionResult DidItWork(string testUserName, string testEmail)`  at it worked fine. Are they the only routes in your route table?

Comment: I get an error `Error 1 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult>'.`

Comment: I didn't include your code within the method obviously, but just comment out all the code in the method and replace with `return null;` to test. In any case its a bit unclear what you doing with this code - what is `var htmlBody ..` for (you don't use it anywhere)? Why are you hard coding values in the route? Why are you returning a view when you dont even use it? etc.

Comment: I still get `null` for my second variable. Also I'm only hard coding the values right now to test it with something I know would work (and because it's shorter than the html that would be returned in the console.log -- I've been using htmlBody when just sending one variable.

Comment: Have you removed the `.` (dot/period character) from the second value?

Comment: Yes, still get `null` for the second value -- based on what you said earlier about it should show `/Test/DidItWork/James%20Bond/james.bond%40gmail.com` there seems like an issue with my `url` -- not quite sure why it's not including the forward slashes after DidItWork and between the 1st and 2nd variable

Comment: Does my DidItWork.cshtml file need anything special? Because I notice if I delete my DidItWork.cshtml file I get an error message and it doesn't send anything... is that supposed to happen?

Comment: Best guess is you have other routes interfering. Are they the only 2 routes in your route table?

Comment: Since you are returning a view for `DidItWork` (not sure why since you dont do anything with it?) then you need the corresponding `.cshtml` file.

Comment: In terms of routes, I haven't created any more; however, my _LoginPartial.cshtml file has @Html.ActionLink...

Comment: There must be something else causing the route to appear that way - it certainly worked for me with the code you have shown

Comment: K, I'll continue to research. Appreciate your help in trying to solve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect it is an encoding issue. There are 2 ways to encode a URL:

- HTML Encoded: `/Home/DidItWork?testUserName=James%20Bond&amp;testEmail=james.bond%40gmail.com`
- URL Encoded: `/Home/DidItWork?testUserName=James%20Bond&testEmail=james.bond%40gmail.com`

When you pass a URL to a web server, it should be URL encoded, otherwise the server won't be able to interpret the `&amp;` sign in the query string.

This would explain why it is working with one variable, but not two.

**Update**

To create a URL without encoding for use with JavaScript, you need to pass the output of `Url.Action` to `Html.Raw`.

```
var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("DidItWork", "Home", new { testUserName = "James Bond", testEmail = "james.bond@gmail.com" }))';
```

Comment: So yeah someone else explained to me that since I'm invoking an action using javascript, I should not be using server side view rendering such as Html.Action but rather client side scripting using Url.Action -- does the Url.Action automatically encode it or do I need to specifically encode it using the Url Encoding you mention above? And if yes, how so?

Comment: Awesome. Using `Html.Raw` worked and I can now pass multiple variables. Thanks again for your explanation and feedback.

Comment: It works GREAT! Thanks! Now i can pass multiple params via ajax.